# How to type hint an overloaded decorator that may be sync or async

Tags: python, overloading, mypy, python-decorators, python-typing

Python 3.10.

I have written two versions of a logging decorator, one for normal functions and one for async functions. Mypy is happy with these:

```py
from functools import wraps
from inspect import Signature, signature
from logging import getLogger
from typing import Any, Awaitable, Callable, ParamSpec, TypeVar, Union, overload

# You heard it here first: type hinting for decorators is a pain in the arse.
Param = ParamSpec("Param")
RetType = TypeVar("RetType")


def _log_with_bound_arguments(
    func_name: str, func_sig: Signature, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any
) -> None:
    # Cf. <https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.BoundArguments>
    bound_func = func_sig.bind_partial(*args, **kwargs)
    func_params = ", ".join([k + "=" + repr(v) for k, v in bound_func.arguments.items()])
    getLogger().debug("-> %s(%s)", func_name, func_params)


def atrace(func: Callable[Param, Awaitable[RetType]]) -> Callable[Param, Awaitable[RetType]]:
    """Async decorator that safely logs the function call at the debug level."""

    @wraps(func)
    async def async_wrapper(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> RetType:
        _log_with_bound_arguments(func.__qualname__, signature(func), *args, **kwargs)
        return await func(*args, **kwargs)

    return async_wrapper


def trace(func: Callable[Param, RetType]) -> Callable[Param, RetType]:
    """Decorator that safely logs the function call at the debug level."""

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> RetType:
        _log_with_bound_arguments(func.__qualname__, signature(func), *args, **kwargs)
        return func(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapper
```

I would like to consolidate these into a single decorator that I can slap on all functions, async or not. Continuing:

```py
from inspect import iscoroutinefunction
from typing import Union, overload


@overload
def ctrace(func: Callable[Param, RetType]) -> Callable[Param, RetType]: ...


@overload
def ctrace(func: Callable[Param, Awaitable[RetType]]) -> Callable[Param, Awaitable[RetType]]: ...


def ctrace(
    func: Union[Callable[Param, RetType], Callable[Param, Awaitable[RetType]]],
) -> Union[Callable[Param, RetType], Callable[Param, Awaitable[RetType]]]:
    if iscoroutinefunction(func):

        @wraps(func)
        async def async_wrapper(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> RetType:
            _log_with_bound_arguments(func.__qualname__, signature(func), *args, **kwargs)
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return async_wrapper
    else:

        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> RetType:
            _log_with_bound_arguments(func.__qualname__, signature(func), *args, **kwargs)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper
```

However, now Mypy is giving me four errors I can't figure out how to fix:

```
src/my_package/log/__init__.py:109: error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2  [misc]
src/my_package/log/__init__.py:109: error: Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 2  [misc]
src/my_package/log/__init__.py:118: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "RetType"  [no-any-return]
src/my_package/log/__init__.py:127: error: Incompatible return value type (got "RetType | Awaitable[RetType]", expected "RetType")  [return-value]
```

The line numbers obviously don't help a lot, so I'll point out that line 109 is the `def ctrace(` line that starts the implementation of the overloaded function. 118 is `return await func(*args, **kwargs)` and 127 is `return func(*args, **kwargs)`.

Pylance only shows a single error: on line 127, *Expression of type "RetType@ctrace | Awaitable[RetType@ctrace]" cannot be assigned to return type "RetType@ctrace"
Type "RetType@ctrace | Awaitable[RetType@ctrace]" cannot be assigned to type "RetType@ctrace"* This is the same as the fourth error from Mypy as far as I can tell.

Any help in hinting this properly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe there is a fix for this, other than (1) not combining the decorators, or (2) telling mypy to ignore those lines. It's a bit "strange" to combine wrappers for async and non-async functions, and the mypy + pylance errors underline that. But this might be the one usecase were it does make sense to do so. I would ask on the discuss.python.org site (makers of mypy+pylance are also there).

Comment: I wouldn't try to combine these two decorators, no matter how *syntactically* similar the two wrappers look.

Comment: @chepner Why not? I am not trying to merge then due to similarity of syntax, it is due to similarity of functionality. What I am trying to avoid is having my co-developers pick the wrong decorator by accident and then wondering what is going wrong.

Comment: They aren't that similar, functionally; one returns a function, the other a coroutine. There's a reason `await` is a keyword, and not just a decorator itself.

Comment: @chepner indeed, despite different nature of these objects, these decorators are doing exactly the same thing: given a callable or coroutine, return another callable or coroutine (same kind) with added logging step. I don't agree that merging them is logically flawed. The problem of current implementation is bad narrowing by [`iscoroutinefunction`](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/f337eb8a5149a05528d19605b7ddd0bc9b5125e4/stdlib/inspect.pyi#L216), and probably can't be solved without `cast`s or ignore comments.

Comment: My objection is that `ctrace`  doesn't reduce any duplications; it's essentially just `def ctrace(f): return atrace(f) if iscoroutinefunction(f) else trace(f)`, and you can't really do anything about it because the need for `async` and `await` keywords *forces* you to duplicate it all. The only thing you gain is the ability to remember one decorator name instead of two, but there are already numerous places where you are forced to distinguish between the two, so this doesn't save you much.